# Logging by NLog in the Model class of Asp.Net core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, nlog

I want to logging model class with nlog.
But, an exception occurs 
because the constructor that takes a log as an argument is not called.

My model class:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using NLog.Extensions.Logging;

public class MyModel
{
    private ILogger<MyController> _logger = null;
    public MyVariable _myVar = null;

    // Constructor
    public MyModel()
    {
        // Required initialize.
        MyProp = new MyVariable();
    }

    // Constructor(With logger)
    public MyModel(ILogger<MyModel> logger)
    {
        MyProp = new MyVariable();
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public MyModel DoSomething(){
        // do shomething...

        _logger.LogTrace("Trace");
        // => NullReferenceException occurred.
        // => Because _logger is null.
        return this;
    }
}
```

My controller class:

```cs
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public IActionResult DoSomething()
    {
        var model = new MyModel();
        return View(model.DoSomething());
    }
}
```

How can I call a constructor that takes a logger as an argument?

Comment: why are you coupling the logging with your model? and why is it `ILogger<MyController>`? will you be passing controller's instance around?

It'd be better if you can configure the logger with your Dependency Injection framework and let DI take care of it.

Comment: @Aarif ILogger <MyController> is a mistake. Correctly ILogger <MyModel>.Dependency injection allows the Controller class to receive an instance of the logger.
Is it correct to pass an instance of Controller's logger to Model class?

Comment: you shouldn't have logging in your domain/model classes, you should handle it early, or if you have any business logic in models you should throw exceptions and let the logger handle and log these in initial layers.